# Show keyboard in password mode without styling the EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, custom-keyboard, android-keypad

I need the keyboard to be shown in the mode similar to the password input type field, but i dont want to specifically set it to that mode for all the `Edittext`'s in the xml.
My required type is somewhat similar to the image here:
[Sample Keyboard Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6B17.png)
Basically, I want to disable the whole bar that contains the speech and auto complete in it, but want my `EditText` to display the same mode as normal text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following attributes to your `EditText` layout:

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
```

Additionally, add this in `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

For reference, take a look at [this](http://www.scriptscoop2.com/t/f2414883eb4b/in-android-edittext-how-to-remove-suggestions-bar-from-soft-keyboard.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this on the xml:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
```

or

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

or if the code above causes error, try this on your code:

```
txtEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEditText);
txtEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Hope this helps! Goodluck!